# Cannot run Django management command using Docker exec

Tags: django, docker

I've got a Django server running nicely in a Docker container called `loc-vol-web`.

When I try to run Django management commands straight from the host CLI, it just doesn't work:

```
>> docker exec -it loc-vol-web "python /app/src/manage.py migrate"

OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"python /app/src/manage.py migrate\": stat python /app/src/manage.py migrate: no such file or directory": unknown
```

However, all of the following work fine:

```
>> docker exec -it loc-vol-web "python"

Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  3 2020, 23:35:31)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

```
>> docker exec -it loc-vol-web "/bin/bash"

some_user@ce1b1c2ac208:/app$ python /app/src/manage.py

Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[auth]
    changepassword
    createsuperuser

[contenttypes]
    remove_stale_contenttypes

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    sendtestemail
    shell
    showmigrations
    sqlflush
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver

[sessions]
    clearsessions

[staticfiles]
    collectstatic
    findstatic
    runserver

some_user@ce1b1c2ac208:/app$
```

I am not sure why I can't just run `manage.py`.

Comment: Take out the quotes in your `docker exec` command.  (It doesn't work for the same reason that running `"python manage.py ..."` with quotes from your local shell doesn't work, it forces the system to consider the whole thing as one "word".)

Comment: @david-maze, you're a star!!! It works fine without the quotes... :face_palm:

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you run docker:
`docker exec -it loc-vol-web "python /app/src/manage.py migrate"`
It is taking everything in double quotes as the command.

It should be run without double quotes:
`docker exec -it loc-vol-web python /app/src/manage.py migrate`

Comment: Jeeez... :face_palm: this is me being really stupid... Thanks for the answer, I can confirm it works fine without quotes...